# Understanding the process of creating a new account

Tags: recurly

I've started making a form using the recurly.js So in the form I have plan, price, credit card, Name, address all others.  Then I get a token.

What do I do now?

On the server side I do.

```
Recurly.Account account = new Recurly.Account(accountID)
{
    Email = model.Email,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName
};

Recurly.BillingInfo billingInfo = new Recurly.BillingInfo(account)
{
    TokenId = model.recurlyToken
};
billingInfo.Create();
```

The Error I get is

```
Error in created the Recurly Account The information being saved is not valid.
```

Why do I need to resupply the email, first name and last name? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have enough details to help, but the process for creating an account is to:

1. Use Recurly.js or another means to submit sensitive information to obtain a secret token.
2. Then use that token to submit an account, subscription, etc. via the Recurly API.

I use the subscription endpoint to create user accounts and subscribe them to a plan in one step, instead of doing it in multiple steps.

It looks like your using JavaScript (maybe Node) to do your server side code so I would suggest using [Node-Recurly](https://github.com/robrighter/node-recurly) to do your API calls and Recurly.js to handle your sensitive data.